# Binario a decimal con recursividad en Java

Tags: java, recursión, bigdecimal, binario

Tengo diseñado un código para la conversión de binario a decimal, pero no sé hacer este mismo código aplicando recursividad. Realmente tengo muchas dudas en esta área y la lógica que se debe de seguir para implementarlo.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Binariodecimal {
 public static int D=0;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
    String in;
    System.out.println("Dame un número binario");
    in=leer.next();
    int bi=Integer.parseInt(in);
    int or=(in.length()-1);
    if(bi>=0){
        System.out.println();
        conver(bi,or);
     }
    else{
        bi=(bi/-1);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("El número binario: " + bi +  " equivale al decimal:" + D);
        conver(bi,or);
    }
    System.out.println("El número binario: " + bi +  " equivale al decimal:" + D); 
}
public static void conver (int bi,int or){
    if(bi<10){
       int op=(bi%2)*(int)Math.pow(2,or);
       D=D+op;
       return;
    }
    else{
     conver(bi/10,or-1); 
     int op=(bi%2)*(int)Math.pow(2,or);
      D=D+op;
       return;
    }
    }
   }
```

Les agradecería que me pudieran ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continuación te presento una posible solución

```
public class Binary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testBin = "111";
        System.out.println("Binary " + testBin + " is " + toDecimal(testBin));
    }

    public static int toDecimal(String binary) {
        return toDecimalHelper(binary, 0, 0);
    }

    public static int toDecimalHelper(String binary, int number, int power) {
        if (binary.length() != 0) {
            int digit = binary.charAt(binary.length() - 1)  == '0' ? 0 : 1;
            number += digit == 1 ? (int) Math.pow(2, power) : 0;
            return toDecimalHelper(binary.substring(0, binary.length() - 1), number, power + 1);
        } 

        return number;
    }
}
```

Aquí me valgo de una función auxiliar la cuál se encargará de la recursión. Cuando realizas llamados recursivos tienes que primero preguntarte ¿cuál es el caso general? y luego ¿cuál es tu condición de parada?.

Para este ejercicio el caso general es tomar uno de los dígitos que conforman el binario y según su posición en este caso `number`, este caso general se mantiene mientras la longitud del string que contiene tu binario sea diferente de 0. Si esto no se cumple es allí donde hemos encontrado la condición de parada. Finalmente el llamado final de la recursión logrará retornar el valor en decimal deseado.